# What is the percentage of known finite non-abelian groups to known finite abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm curious as to what the percentage of known finite non-abelian groups to known finite abelian groups is. Is there any research or hard data in this direction?

Edit: As we keep discovering more groups will non-abelian groups or abelian groups dominate the percentage?

Comment: You would first have to define percentage here. Do you mean of a fixed (finite) order $n$, up to a fixed finite order $n$, taking the limit in either situation, ... ?

Comment: For groups of order $p^k$ where $k$ isn't very small, there a **lot** of non-isomorphic groups.

Comment: This depends heavily on how you want to define percentage, but my guess is quite different from yours, that there are so many more non-abelian groups of that the limit is $0$.

Comment: your guess is probably right

Comment: If you are thinking of groups up to order $n$, then it tends to $100\%$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: okay so assuming groups up to order $n$ @DerekHolt what tends to 100%? The percentage of non-abelian groups?

Comment: Just looking at the case where $n$ is a prime power, compare [the number of groups of order $n$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Higman-Sims_asymptotic_formula_on_number_of_groups_of_prime_power_order) with [the number of partitions of $n$](http://oeis.org/wiki/Partition_function#Asymptotic_behavior_of_the_partition_function), and note that the latter is the number of abelian groups of order $n$ by the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vast majority of finite groups are 2-groups (that is groups whose order is a power of 2). The vast majority of those 2-groups are non-abelian. There is a classical result (see https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/s3-15/1/151/1534319 ) that the for any prime $p$, the number of groups of size $p^n$ is $p^{\frac{2n^3}{27}}$. It is not hard to see from this (and a little care with the error terms) that the vast majority of groups of size at most $m$ are contained in the $2$ groups. Note that this doesn't assert that they have density 1 (which is as far as I'm aware an open problem). Now, for any prime $p$ and $n$ the number of abelian groups of order $p^n$ is $P(n)$ where $P(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$. The number of partitions of $n$ grows slower than exponential, and so the vast majority of finite groups are non-abelian 2-groups as long as one is counting how many groups there are of order $n$ for large $n$.

Edit: The above isn't quite right it seems. See Verret's comment below. It appears that even the claim that a majority of groups are 2 groups is still open.

Comment: It is only a conjecture that the majority of finite groups are $2$-groups. As far as what's actually known, the density of $2$-groups could be 0. (None of this is directly relevant to the question anyway.)

Comment: @verret, Hmm, you appear to be correct. At least I cannot see an immediate step from Sims's Theorems to the majority being two groups. Do you have a citation for this being an open problem? That's surprising.

Comment: It's described as a folklore conjecture on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group#Among_groups   see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164202/which-finite-groups-can-be-characterized-by-their-subgroup-orders/164218#164218 for a perhaps more authoritative source.

Comment: I can also say from personal experience that's its commonly believed to have been proved (not in the sense that people think they saw a proof, but in the same sense as here, that someone thought it must be known). Just on this website I've made this remark a few times.